# How to allow full use of all available swap space by a process running inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, memory

I have written a test Node app which eats memory (in 100MB chunks). I am trying to get it to continue allocating memory beyond the physical memory limit of 8GB by using the swap space (16GB) which is configured on the Ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) box it is running on.

This is working fine when running in Node, like this (no container):

```
node --max-old-space-size=16384 ./memtest/memtest.js
```

When I run it inside a Docker container, it is being terminated at the limit of physical memory (8GB). Actually it seems to be killed before this at around 3gb. Even with 5gb free it is killed at 3gb.

I have tried some Docker options to try and get it to use the swap space, but it's still getting killed at the same point as with the default memory configuration.

```
docker run -m 8g --memory-swap -1 --memory-swappiness 100 ...

Amount allocated before container is killed: 3037.08 MB

# swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file  16G 187M   -2

# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8148324     1022788     5538364         124     1587172     6813484
Swap:      16777212      191228    16585984
```

From the docs below it would appear that the default behaviour should be to allow unbounded use of memory + swap - as I am trying to achieve. However, I am not seeing this.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

I am seeking to understand the reason why the behaviour is different inside Docker and how to allow *full use of all available swap space* **when the process is running inside a Docker container**.

NB I am not using Docker Desktop, this question is not about Docker Desktop.

UPDATE:

Here is the JS code I'm using to test with:

const bufs = [];

```
function testMemory() {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`${(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2)} MB`);//
    bufs.push(new Array(1e7));
  }, 100);
}

testMemory();
```

Comment: The `docker run -m 8g` option will limit the process to 8 GB of memory use, regardless of the physical resources available.  Does removing that option help?

Comment: @DavidMaze Please see this section from the docs:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details

"--memory-swap is a modifier flag that only has meaning if --memory is also set."

"If --memory-swap is set to a positive integer, then both --memory and --memory-swap must be set. --memory-swap represents the total amount of memory and swap that can be used, and --memory controls the amount used by non-swap memory."

Comment: My baseline expectation here would be that you need to do absolutely nothing; just plain `docker run` with no memory-related options would let it use physical RAM and/or swap in the same way a non-container process does.  Do you see that behavior as well, or is the process somehow prevented from using swap?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I agree, but testing shows that the container is killed after exhausting physical memory (tested on Ubuntu) - both with and without the above options. Somehow, it is prevented from using swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all of your assumptions. Can you be sure that the process is being killed at the limit of physical memory? Is it possible that the process is terminating for another reason? Are there any differences between how the process is run inside Docker and your example with just Node that behaves as expected?

Using all of the host's resources is the default behaviour of Docker so it would appear that the cause of the issue is elsewhere.